# IAM Policy to prevent DynamoDB from creating records for UpdateItem

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

My application allows users direct access to DynamoDB from their browser. They can view and edit any record for which they know the partition key (a UUID).

My problem is that users can create new records by 'editing' a non-existant partition key. Is there a way to use an IAM policy to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AWS Cognito to build fine-grained Access Control to your DynamoDB Table.

You can do it with code with a Lambda, you need to write all the Authorization Logic in code.

**Reference to fine-grained Authorization:**

It also includes row-level authorization and as well as table level authorization, merged with AWS Cognito.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools-groups/

Hope it helps.

**EDIT1:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/api-permissions-reference.html

**dynamodb:PutItem**  will prevent users from updating dynamodb records.

Example Policy:

```
 {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "AllowAccessToOnlyItemsMatchingUserID",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "dynamodb:GetItem",
                    "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                    "dynamodb:Query",
                    "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/TableName"
                ]
            }
        ]
}
```

Gives all permission reference to create IAM policy to block users to create new records.

**Conditional Update:**

> Edits an existing item's attributes, or adds a new item to the table
>   if it does not already exist. You can put, delete, or add attribute
>   values. You can also perform a conditional update on an existing item
>   (insert a new attribute name-value pair if it doesn't exist, or
>   replace an existing name-value pair if it has certain expected
>   attribute values).

Comment: I'm not using Lambda, this is direct access from the browser to DynamoDB. The users are public, so we cannot create individual records in Cognito for each user. My question is whether or not IAM policies can be configured to prevent creation of new records in DynamoDB, while allowing editing of existing records.

Comment: If you are using keys to access from browser, you can control to that role with IAM policy. Updating the answer.

Comment: The problem is that UpdateItem will also create a new record, if you provide a non-existent partition key as the item to update.

Comment: Perform a conditional Update, instead of straight update, it will not insert new item.

Comment: But that's a client-side decision. I want to be able to enforce that with a server-side IAM policy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConditionExpression to only do the update if a certain criteria is met. Since all items must have a hash key (primary key), you can use a ConditionExpression to only do the update if the hash key exists, which will only be true for existing items. Therefore UpdateItem will only update existing items, not create new ones.

For example:

`ConditionExpression: 'attribute_exists(myHashKey)'`

Comment: But there's no way to enforce this in the IAM policy, right? So anybody with the credentials could create new records, without doing the conditional update.

Comment: Apologies, I see what you mean, no I don't think there's a way to do that in IAM sadly. The closest I can think of would be to use the LeadingKeys IAM condition so that users could only create or edit items where the hash key begins with their user id.